# 3D Quadrature schemes with points on boundary

Tags: finite-element, quadrature, 3d, numerical-integration

In one dimension there are two types of quadrature schemes.

1. ***asymmetric*** rules like [Newton-Cotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Cotes_formulas) like formulas (Trapezodi, Simpson), and [Clenshaw-Curtis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clenshaw%E2%80%93Curtis_quadrature) place sampling points on boundary of the interval.
2. ***symmetric*** [Gaussian Quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature) use only internal points which never tough the boundary.

Clear advantage of ***asymmeric*** formulas with boundary points is that one can re-use the function values on the boundary of domain for neighboring domains. For example If I have tetraheral mesh I can use the values for sampling points placed on vertexes, edges and faces for all neighboring tetrahedra.

However, when I was searching in literature I mostly found ***symmetric*** 2D and 3D quadrature schemes with just internal points (especially for tetrahedra, pyramids etc.). For example:

- [Polyquad](https://github.com/PyFR/Polyquad) [quadpy](https://github.com/sigma-py/quadpy) looks great but it is all ***symmetric***
- [in this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042712001604) symetric rules are also develped
- There is what I want for [2D trinagle](https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/f_src/triangle_fekete_rule/triangle_fekete_rule.html) (not for 3D tetrahedron)

**Qustions:**

- Do you know some ***asymetric*** rules for 3D objects like tetrahedron, pyramid etc. ?
- why symmetric rules are preferend ?

Comment: Gauss-Lobatto rules include the extreme of the interval.

Comment: You can't reuse if the function you are integrating has discontinuity over element boundary. In fact, you'd need to somehow distinguish between these two cases which sounds cumbersome.

Comment: @nicoguaro OK, but how are Gauss-Lobatto rules defined for tetrahedron ?

Comment: @knl OK, but I don't have discontinuous functions